The 2nd FTDI device on the same bus is not recognized
I have connected 2 relay cards, each with an FTDI, to the same USB port on the Raspberry Pi 5. I first routed the USB cable to the first relay card and then on to the next relay card. Just like in a parallel circuit. Only the first connected relay card is recognized. When I address the relay cards, only the relay card shown is switched. I think the relay cards connected to the same bus one after the other should all be recognized and not just the relay card that has been connected to the bus the longest. The serial number only differs in the last digit. What can I do so that the second relay card is also recognized?
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12

lothar@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | tail
[  932.612173] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci-hcd
[  932.809129] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[  932.809136] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  932.809140] usb 3-2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[  932.809142] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[  932.809145] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: AD01US0W
[  932.822321] ftdi_sio 3-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[  932.822371] usb 3-2: Detected FT232R
[  932.830461] usb 3-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 4162.851510] v3d 1002000000.v3d: MMU error from client PTB (1) at 0x21b61000, pte invalid

lothar@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | tail
[ 6086.000852] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci-hcd
[ 6086.340876] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 6086.645148] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[ 6086.645156] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6086.645159] usb 3-2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[ 6086.645161] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 6086.645164] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: AD01US0X
[ 6086.658207] ftdi_sio 3-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 6086.658251] usb 3-2: Detected FT232R
[ 6086.666311] usb 3-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0


connected 2 relay cards to the same USB port ... what does that mean?  ... please update your post with a clear description of what you actually did

I first routed the USB cable to the first relay card and then on to the next relay card. Just like in a parallel circuit.

why would you expect that to work? ... writing a comment is not an update to your post ... please use the edit button below your question
